# Internal error when training a model in AUTOML-tables

Tags: google-cloud-automl

Previously I was able to successfully train a small dataset (approx 45k rows)

`gs://cloud-ml-tables-data/bank-marketing.csv`

using Google AutoML-tables with decent accuracy. Now, I would want to train another dataset with nearly 1 million rows spread across 5 classes.

When I start the training, after sometime I receive "INTERNAL Error".
I receive the email with the subject

> AutoML Tables was unable to train model [model_name]

and this content:

> "Hello AutoML Tables Customer, 
>  Due to an error, AutoML Tables was
>   unable to train 
>  model '[model_name]'.
>  Additional Details:
>   
>  Resource Name: projects/[...]/locations/us-central1/models/[...]
>   
>  Operation State: Failed with errors 
>  Error Messages:
>   INTERNAL"

I am not given the details of the error.

What might be causing this? Is this a problem of the dataset that I am using?
 
Any help on how to debug/solve this issue, would be greatly appreciated.
 Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your dataset contains duplicate columns.

If so, clean your dataset and try it again.

If not, try to execute another training run with exactly the same data.

Note that [AutoML Tables](https://cloud.google.com/automl-tables/) stills on Beta stage so this issues should be fixed overtime.